# Split a string while preserving values wrapped in quotes (.NET)

Tags: .net

I'm looking for a way, in .NET, to split a string while ignoring split characters that are within quotes (or another delimiter). (This functionality would match what a typical CSV parser does if the split delimiter is a comma.) I'm not sure why this ability isn't built into `String.Split()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table. Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177511/input-array-is-longer-than-the-number-of-columns-in-this-table-exception)

Comment: @Pat: What about if you have escaped delimiters? `'Here\'s, an example'` Getting this right is difficult. It's probably best to use a dedicated CSV parser instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: So funny as I thought of the same one. Guess I should have just mentioned it as a duplicate possibly. Though I think his is different because he doesn't want to deal with just csv.

Comment: @spinon - the reader mentioned in the other question allows most standard delimiters / patterns.

Comment: oh well then there you go Pat. Sounds like you should check that out. Thanks @Marc. I think I am going to keep that in mind as well.

Comment: Thanks for the links to the other post. That CSV parser is nice, but it fails in one instance. When the input is `"\"a, a\" <a@a.a>, \"a, a\" <a@a.a>"`, I expect the output to be two identical strings of `"\"a, a\" <a@a.a>"`. The CSV parser instead throws an exception - I guess that the mix of quoted and non-quoted strings isn't allowed in CSV, even though it is used for parsing email addresses (which is what I am doing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for that. Example:

```
string test = @"this,i""s,a"",test";
string[] parts =
  Regex.Matches(test, @"(""[^""]*""|[^,])+")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Value)
  .ToArray();

foreach (string s in parts) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
this
i"s,a"
test
```

Comment: Nice! This method works well for everything I need. I added a `.Select(m => m.Value.Trim())` to clean things up.

Comment: didn't work my test case, "java.exe -cp \"a stupid jar with a space.jar\" my.MainClass" which should have returned a 4 parts, but i ended up with one

Comment: @spy: The example uses comma as a separator. You would need to use a space instead of the comma in the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Marc's answer in this post:

[Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table. Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177511/input-array-is-longer-than-the-number-of-columns-in-this-table-exception/3177522#3177522)

He mentions a library you can use for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Guffa's method, here is my full solution:

```
/// <summary>
/// Splits the string while preserving quoted values (i.e. instances of the delimiter character inside of quotes will not be split apart).
/// Trims leading and trailing whitespace from the individual string values.
/// Does not include empty values.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The string to be split.</param>
/// <param name="delimiter">The delimiter to use to split the string, e.g. ',' for CSV.</param>
/// <returns>A collection of individual strings parsed from the original value.</returns>
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitWhilePreservingQuotedValues(this string value, char delimiter)
{
    Regex csvPreservingQuotedStrings = new Regex(string.Format("(\"[^\"]*\"|[^{0}])+", delimiter));
    var values =
        csvPreservingQuotedStrings.Matches(value)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value.Trim())
        .Where(v => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v));
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to allow single quote (') then change the expression to @"(""[^""]*""|'[^']*'|[^\s])+".

If you want to remove the quotes from the string then change your Select to .Select(m => m.Value.Trim(new char [] {'\'','"'})).